# is there a way to create custom validation rules that can be reuse for Livewire without using Form Request in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Since laravel can use custom validation rules when using Request validation

```
public function store(ModelStoreRequest $request) {
      //
}
```

is there a way to reuse a custom validation rules without using request ? I am using a livewire and it doesn't need to use request.

```
public function store() {
     $this->validate([
        'foo' => 'required'
     ]);
}
```

Comment: Validation rules are in request class stored in public method, so you can just get then from there `$rules = (new ModelStoreRequest)->rules();` and use in Livewire.

Comment: thank you so much!